# keep making changes to the same git repository after copying the project from git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I was working on a rails project. It is saved on my git repository aswell. But yesterday i got errors on my rails project and deleted it along with the developing environment(ruby on rails). I reinstalled everything and now no issues.

I downloaded the previously saved repository in zip format from github. I then extracted and copied the folder contents (inside the master folder file) to a directory with a same file name as before. How can i continue to make changes to the same repository as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of downloading via zip, you need to clone the repository. Here's an example:

```
git clone git@github.com:rubycuts/enumerables.git
```

This will create a directory called "enumerables", and load the repository into it.  If you want the created folder to have a different name, just append the name you want to the command:

```
git clone git@github.com:rubycuts/enumerables.git somethingelse
```

Either way, you'll be able to use the repository as if it had always been there. The one exception is anything that matches your .gitignore file, which git of course ignores. In Rails applications, the config/database.yml file is often added to .gitignore so private database information is not stored in the repository.